# PHP array with two this same key (SOAP)

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to comunicate with DHL API (SOAP). I can make a new parcel, but when I make a shipment with extra services, I must build the query with two (or more) ITEM keys like:

```
<specialServices>
    <item>
        <serviceType>UBEZP</serviceType>
        <serviceValue>10000</serviceValue>
    </item>
    <item>
        <serviceType>COD</serviceType>
        <serviceValue>2000</serviceValue>
    </item>
</specialServices>
```

I tried it like this, but the DHL system didn't work:

```
'specialServices' => array(
    'collectOnDeliveryForm' => 'BANK_TRANSFER',
    'item' => array(
        array(
            'serviceType' => 'UBEZP',
            'serviceValue' => '10000'
        ),
        array(
            'serviceType' => 'COD',
            'serviceValue' => '1000'
        )
    )
)
```

and like this, but PHP can only use one key with this same name, so the second key rewrites the first:

```
'specialServices' => array(
    'collectOnDeliveryForm' => 'BANK_TRANSFER',
    'item' => array(
        'serviceType' => 'UBEZP',
        'serviceValue' => '10000'
    ),
    'item' => array(
        'serviceType' => 'COD',
        'serviceValue' => '5000'
    )
)
```

Comment: I would suggest referring to their xml or soap API,sometimes you have to put the nested arrays in a data element, such as array( 'data' => array('item => array(..),array()), this is done so you could add attributes to the xml tags, usually done with the '@attributes' tag etc..